# If user enter not correct data app must repeats question

Tags: go, command-line-interface

everyone! I'm newbie in Golang and I've a problem.
I've some code like this (just example):

```
fmt.Println("yes or no:")
if _, err := fmt.Scan(&str); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if str == "no" {
    fmt.Println("You have to enter yes.")
    //What do I need to write this?
}
```

I wont it shows the question "yes or no" again til an user enters correct data or terminate proccess.

Comment: You have to put this block in a loop. and check the answer everytime until the loop can exit. There is no golang specific problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a while loop (for in Go) to continuously loop until you get an input you want.

```
var keepRepeating = true

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

for keepRepeating {

    fmt.Println("Enter y/n")    
    scanner.Scan()
    if scanner.Text() == "y" {
        keepRepeating = false
    }
    if scanner.Text() == "n" {
        keepRepeating = false       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, everyone! I did so:

```
for {
    fmt.Println("yes or no:")
    if _, err := fmt.Scan(&str); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if str == "no" {
        fmt.Println("enter again")
    } else {
        break
    }
}
```